# How to monitor the last PID assigned by the kernel?

Tags: ubuntu, scripting, posix, pid

To monitor process creation I'd like to periodically write the last PID assigned by the kernel to *any* process on the system (not just processes created by the PID-monitoring program) with a time stamp to a file (using a daemon to avoid creating any extra processes). Any language would be fine, but I have a feeling this should be possible (even easy) in POSIX shell.

Answer (score 4):

This saves the timestamp and last PID to file every second in Bash, using the [`ns_last_pid`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/sysctl/kernel.html#ns-last-pid) sysctl:

> The last pid allocated in the current (the one task using this sysctl lives in) pid namespace.

```bash
old=""
while read < /proc/sys/kernel/ns_last_pid
do
    if [ "$REPLY" != "$old" ]
    then
        printf '%(%s)T %d\n' -1 "$REPLY"
        old=$REPLY
    fi
    read -t 1 || true
done > pids.log
```

Problems:

- `/proc/sys/kernel/ns_last_pid` is only [available in Linux 3.3](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/b8f566b04d3cddd192cfd2418ae6d54ac6353792) and newer
- The `printf` `%(fmt)T` specifier is only [available in Bash 4.2](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/NEWS?h=bash-4.2&id=495aee441b75276e38c75694ccb455bb6463fdb9#n42) and newer
- [POSIX `read`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/read.html) doesn't have the `-t` option.
- Can't use `sleep`, `cat` or other non-builtins, since they would use additional PIDs.

Comment: */proc/sys/kernel/ns_last_pid is not available everywhere.* Most notably, /proc is only available on Linux...

Comment: All the non-POSIX idioms in there have actually been borrowed by `bash` from the Korn shell. So it's not `bash` specific, its `ksh93/bash` specific. Note that `sleep` is builtin in `ksh93` and it also has a `cat` builtin (only enabled if `/opt/ast/bin` is before `/bin` (or wherever the system `cat` is) in `$PATH`). POSIX doesn't specify which commands are builtin.

Comment: Odd, I don't have that file on several Linux boxes I checked, but they do have pid namespace support. One is even using namespaces...

Comment: That file doesn't exist on any Red Hat distros I have (Fedora 14,17 + CentOS 5,6). Ubuntu 12.10 has it.

Answer (score 2):

POSIX doesn't provide a way to get the last PID assigned by the kernel so there can't be a portable answer.

Here is a oneliner that should work on all systems implementing dtrace (Solaris, FreeBSD, NetBSD, Mac OS X, Oracle Linux with latest UEK, and others like Illumos based OSes, Linux with [dtrace4linux](https://github.com/dtrace4linux))

```
# dtrace -qn 'proc:::exec-success { printf("%Y - %d\n",walltimestamp,pid); }'
2013 May 15 00:48:47 - 1276
2013 May 15 00:48:49 - 1277
2013 May 15 00:48:52 - 1278
```

Edit:

On Linux, an alternative would be to use [systemtap](http://sourceware.org/systemtap/) if available with which this command (untested) should provide a similar output:

```
# stap -e 'probe syscall.execve { printf("%s - %d\n",ctime(gettimeofday_s()),pid()); }'
```

Comment: @l0b0 As I wrote, you need an OS with dtrace installed which is obviously not the case with your test machine. There are a couple of dtrace implementations with Linux: Oracle Linux 6.4 with UEK and dtrace4linux. You might also use systemtap. Answer updated.

Comment: @l0b0 Answer updated again, I'm still unsure about if pid need to be called as a function or used as a variable.

Comment: There's no syntax error anymore, but "missing x86_64 kernel/module debuginfo under '/lib/modules/3.5.0-27-generic/build' while resolving probe point kernel.function("do_execve").call". `apt-cache search debuginfo` doesn't reveal anything useful, so I guess this isn't possible on my distro.

Comment: @l0b0 Your question is tagged POSIX and as I wrote there cannot be a POSIX way to match your requirements. You'd rather tell what your distribution is.